# UWP and BitmapDecoder Issue - Feels like a threading issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, asynchronous, uwp

## UWP and BitmapDecoder Issue

I have an issue in a UWP app that needs to create a BitmapDecoder.

- If I run in MainForm.xaml.cs, it works.
- If this code lives in another CS module, it freezes.

```
decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(ras);
```

I've tried some techniques using the Dispatcher to no avail:

```
await Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.High,
  async () =>
  {
     decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(ras);
  });
```

### Theory

I must be blocking the UI thread. I've tried different techniques to free myself from the UI but haven't been successful.

Here is the way I implemented it and it works. Is the best way to do it. It was mentioned that I should not be using "async void." So any return value is better than void?

MainForm.xaml.cs

```
        private async void ConvertToMarkdown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                await Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    await openXmlLib.main(src, folder);
                });
            }
        }
```

**openXmlLib.cs** is just a class module. main() is just a method.

#### This code doesn't work

```
        private async void ConvertToMarkdown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             await openXmlLib.main(src, folder);
        }
```

**Any clues would be appreciated.**

Comment: Maybe a hack but it works when I call the external routine (main()) from MainPage.xaml, I need to run as task:



                    await Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        await myLib.main(src, myfile);
                    });

Comment: What is RAS? I assume an `IRandomAccessStream` but does it have a custom implementation? Without knowing what you mean by "another CS module" and under what threading context you use it in MainForm.xaml.cs, it's hard to make any determination as to threading etc. Can you show more code and provide more info?

Comment: How do you call the code when it is outside of `MainForm.xaml.cs`? From an event handler? Could you provide source code for it? Are you sure the code doesn't in fact throw an exception instead, which is masked (for example due to a `async void` method)?

Comment: The [`Dispatcher.RunAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync) method does not accept async delegates. So your async lambda is treated as `async void`, which [should be avoided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void).